# Sympy failed to render matrix

Tags: matplotlib, sympy

I'm using IPython's Qtconsole  and use default setting of printing setting.
It works well for polynomial, but do not work for Matrix

```
from sympy import init_printing, Matrix
init_printing()
a=Matrix([1,2])
a
```

the error is

```
ValueError: 
\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1\\2\end{smallmatrix}\right]
      ^
Expected "\right" (at char 6), (line:1, col:7)
```

I have tried http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php and it seems the latex code is correct.
I have tried the dev version of sympy, it still doesn't work. I did not try dev version of matplotlib yet. Because there're only source for the dev version.

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: I'm using python 3.4. I tried installing a latex , then sympy will use latex to render the equation. It works, but I don't think it's the solution.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: It is a known issue, yet to be solved. You need to use a proper LaTeX.

Your problem might be related to [this](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/9799). The problem is due to `matplotlibs` very limited understanding of LaTeX. In this case the `\begin{...}` flag cannot be interpreted by `matplotlib`, although it is valid LaTeX.