# ParseSyntaxException while plotting sympy matrix

Tags: matplotlib, matrix, label, sympy, parse-error

Here is the code that produces error, I tried different approaches, but they all throw an error:

```
from sympy import Matrix, latex
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = Matrix([1, 2])
plt.plot([0, 0], label=latex(a, mode='inline'))

# also produces error
# plt.plot([0, 0], label=f"${latex(a)}$")
# plt.plot([0, 0], label=fr"${latex(a)}$")

plt.legend()
```

Comment: Can't test, but what is the result after adding `plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True`?

Comment: Maybe [How to write your own LaTeX preamble in Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453109/how-to-write-your-own-latex-preamble-in-matplotlib/41453758#41453758) is helpful? Also related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30015110/sympy-failed-to-render-matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30015110/sympy-failed-to-render-matrix). Does it work with other sympy expressions? Which versions of matplotlib/sympy? What are the exact error message and error trace?

Comment: `plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True` not working( It says: "RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found"

Comment: JohanC, other expressions work great. matplotlib: 3.7.1 and sympy: 1.12. Here is error message: https://paste.pics/QFPMX